# Python ValueError when try to use pandas df.loc with panel data

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I have panel data and I want to find the combinations of different elements. In other words, I just wanna take the combinations of "A"s with "B"s. here is to code that I tried to run :

```
moving_distance = ((x, y, ((x+y)/22) for x, y in combinations(df['distance'], 2) if df.loc[df.distance == x, 'name'] != df.loc[df.distance == y, 'name'])
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

How I could solve my problem ?

**Edit**
data looks like this

```
name         distance
BMW-2012     10
BMW-2013     5 
BMW-2014     12
WW_2009      2
WW_2010      4
Mer_2010     5
Mer_2011     8
```

I want to get the combinations of different engines(i.e. names) and their covered distances, and use it in a function
Desired Output is

```
name       distance combinations              combined distance
BMW-2012   10       [(BMW-2012,WW_2009),      [45, 52, 65, 88]
                    (BMW-2012,WW_2010),         
                    (BMW-2012,Mer_2010), 
                    (BMW-2012,Mer_2010]
```

Then the same for BMW_2013, BMW_2014,WW_2009 and so on and so forth. The only thing is I don't wanna match BMWs with BMWs and WWs with WWs

Comment: No answer so far :(

Comment: You have no answer, because it's not clear what are you trying to achieve... The subject states "Panel", but there is no Panel in the question. Can you provide a reproducible data set and desired data set?

Comment: Yeah sure, I am doing right away